# Sort first array based on second array issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, d3.js

I am trying to sort a JavaScript array based on sort order in a second array. I have already gone through other similar questions here in SO and came up with the below code. Be the output is not getting as expected.

```
var legends = ["Maths","Physics","English","French","Chemistry"];
var sortOrder = [1,400,300,200,-3];

legends.sort( function (a, b) {
    return sortOrder[legends.indexOf(a)] >= sortOrder[legends.indexOf(b)];   
  });


console.log(legends);
```

The desired output is

```
["Chemistry", "Maths", "French", "English", "Physics"];
```

- Chemistry denotes the sort order -3
- Maths next higher count, that is  1
- French next higher count, that is 200

I am trying to get the desired output either in pure JS or using D3js, not sure if I am doing it right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost right but in the sort function, you refer to `legends` array which is being mutated, so indexes does not match to original order.

To demonstrate that this is the case, you could copy the array and sort the copy:

```js
var legends = ["Maths","Physics","English","French","Chemistry"];
var legendsToSort = ["Maths","Physics","English","French","Chemistry"];

var sortOrder = [1,400,300,200,-3];

legendsToSort.sort( function (a, b) {
    return sortOrder[legends.indexOf(a)] >= sortOrder[legends.indexOf(b)];   
  });


console.log(legendsToSort);
```

Comment: very funny. just to mention a possible drawback of this.

Comment: not being funny here, I thank you for pointing out this problem. I just wanted to help OP understand why his method wasn't working, not to give a better solution

Comment: @Francesco sort values are not unique, it can be like [1,5,5,4,-3] and legends will be unique as it will be plotted in a graph. But the point as you mentioned is, my array array was getting mutated.

Comment: @NinaScholz its a good point, but my legends array will not have duplicates.

Comment: Accepted the answer, but unable to upvote due to low reputation ;(

Answer (score 3):

You could take a helper array with indices, sort them and map the wanted array.

```js
var legends = ["Maths", "Physics", "English", "French", "Chemistry"],
    sortOrder = [1, 400, 300, 200, -3];

legends = [...legends.keys()]
    .sort((a, b) => sortOrder[a] - sortOrder[b])
    .map(i => legends[i]);        

console.log(legends);
```

Comment: It helped, wish I could upvote, but unable due to low reputation, new here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```js
var legends = ["Maths","Physics","English","French","Chemistry"];
var sortOrder = [1,400,300,200,-3];

/* Create an array of objects of value index of sortOrder */
legends = Object.entries(sortOrder.reduce((a,v,i) => Object.assign(a, {[v]:i}), {}))
.sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0]) // Sort array based on sortOrder values
.map(([s, i]) => legends[i]); // fetch items from legends based on sorted order 

console.log(legends);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, wish I could upvote, but unable due to low reputation, new here ;)