# Sorting an array based on property value of another array of objects

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array of objects:

```
var list = [
       { name: "A", distance: 1},
       { name: "B", distance: 2},
       { name: "C", distance: 3},
       { name: "D", distance: 4},
       { name: "E", distance: 5},
       { name: "F", distance: 6},
       { name: "G", distance: 7},
       { name: "H", distance: 8} 
    ];
```

if I have another array like this one :

```
var disturbed = ["G", "B", "C", "F"];
```

how can I sort `disturbed array` based on `distance property` from the `list array` like this:

```
["B", "C", "F", "G"];
```

Edit: I have tried this code with no success:

```
items = [ 
       { name: "A", distance: 1},
       { name: "B", distance: 2},
       { name: "C", distance: 3},
       { name: "D", distance: 4},
       { name: "E", distance: 5},
       { name: "F", distance: 6},
       { name: "G", distance: 7},
       { name: "H", distance: 8}
]

sorting = [ 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ];
result = []
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
sorting.forEach(function(key) {
    var found = false;
    items = items.filter(function(item) {

        if(!found && items[i].distance == key) {
            result.push(item);
            found = true;
            return false;
        } else 
            return true;
    })
})

result.forEach(function(item) {
    document.writeln(item[i]) 
})
}
```

How can I Sort an array based on the property value of another array of objects

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755037/sort-first-array-based-on-second-array-issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to change the `list` array to object and then sort based on this object.

Demo:

```js
var list = [
       { name: "A", distance: 1},
       { name: "B", distance: 2},
       { name: "C", distance: 3},
       { name: "D", distance: 4},
       { name: "E", distance: 5},
       { name: "F", distance: 6},
       { name: "G", distance: 7},
       { name: "H", distance: 8} 
    ];
    
var disturbed = ["G", "B", "C", "F"];
    
var sort = list.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.name] = cur.distance;
  return acc;
}, {});

disturbed.sort((a, b) => sort[a] - sort[b]);

console.log(disturbed)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the object with the specified `name` property that matches your elements in `distributed`. Once you have got this you can then get the distance property and calculate the difference to sort accordingly:

```js
const list = [
  { name: "A", distance: 1},
  { name: "B", distance: 2},
  { name: "C", distance: 3},
  { name: "D", distance: 4},
  { name: "E", distance: 5},
  { name: "F", distance: 6},
  { name: "G", distance: 7},
  { name: "H", distance: 8} 
];

const disturbed = ["G", "B", "C", "F"];

const res = disturbed.sort((a, b) => {
  const {distance: d_a} = list.find(({name}) => name === a);
  const {distance: d_b} = list.find(({name}) => name === b);
  return d_a - d_b;
});

console.log(res);
```

A more efficient approach would be to create a [`new Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then use `.sort()` on the keys form the map:

```js
const list = [
  { name: "A", distance: 1},
  { name: "B", distance: 2},
  { name: "C", distance: 3},
  { name: "D", distance: 4},
  { name: "E", distance: 5},
  { name: "F", distance: 6},
  { name: "G", distance: 7},
  { name: "H", distance: 8} 
];
const disturbed = ["G", "B", "C", "F"];

const lut = new Map(list.map(({name, distance}) => [name, distance]));
const res = disturbed.sort((a, b) => lut.get(a) - lut.get(b));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `.find` inside a `sort` is very inefficient though, something like `O(log n² * n²)`

Comment: @JonasWilms yeah, I agree it's not very efficient. I was going to suggest a better approach but _Cuong Le Ngoc_ provided that

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sort` method to do that

```
var list = [
       { name: "A", distance: 1},
       { name: "B", distance: 2},
       { name: "C", distance: 3},
       { name: "D", distance: 4},
       { name: "E", distance: 5},
       { name: "F", distance: 6},
       { name: "G", distance: 7},
       { name: "H", distance: 8} 
    ];

var disturbed = ["G", "B", "C", "F"];

disturbed.sort((a, b) => {
    var itemA = list.find(item => item.name === a);
    var itemB = list.find(item => item.name === b);
    return itemA.distance - itemB.distance;
});

disturbed.forEach(function(item) {
    document.writeln(item[i]) 
})
```